# is there an equivalent of FileTypeImageUtils for Alfresco Share?

Tags: share, alfresco

I need to retrieve the icon of a content file based on its media type.

I know that in Alfresco Explorer you could use the FileTypeImageUtils.getFileTypeImage() method.

Is there something equivalent in Share?

Comment: There's a rest API you can call, is that of use? Or do you want to do it in server side JS?

Comment: I want to do it client side in the js. for the moment I just hack it like this: `icon: Alfresco.constants.URL_RESCONTEXT + "components/images/filetypes/" + myJson.extension + "-file-32.png"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the file icon, or the file thumbnail?

If you're on Alfresco 4.0, the URL to request the thumbnail of a document is /proxy/alfresco/api/node/workspace/[Store]/[ID]/content/thumbnails/doclib?c=queue&ph=true eg 
http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/62d652d5-5759-434e-8739-295fa3447481/content/thumbnails/doclib?c=queue&ph=true

The way to build that is usually:

```
Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + 'api/node/' + nodeRef.uri + '/content/thumbnails/doclib?c=queue&ph=true"
```

If you do just want the icon, then the code is something like:

```
Alfresco.constants.URL_RESCONTEXT + 'components/images/filetypes/' + Alfresco.util.getFileIcon(name)
```